# I cant delete my quotes in Django? Python

Tags: python, django

Ive created a Django project where people can enter quotes by different authors. I cant figure out why Im not able to delete quotes on the same page. The user should be able to delete there own quotes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome, {{request.session.greeting}}</h1>
        <a href='/Edit_Account'>Edit My Account</a>
        <a href='/logout'>Logout</a>
    </header>

    {% for quote in quotes %}
        <p>Posted on: {{review.created_at}}</p>
        {% if quote.user.id == request.session.user_id %}
        <a href='reviews/{{quote.id}}/delete'>Delete this quote</a>
        {% endif %}
        <li>{{quote.author}} {{quote.quote}}</li>
        <a href="/like/{{quote.id}}">Like Quote</a>
        <p>{{ quote.user_likes.count }}</p>
        <p>(Posted by </a><a href='/users/{{quote.user.id}}'>{{quote.creator.first_name}}) </a></p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{message}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <h2>Add A Quote!</h2>
    <form action="quote/create" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input type="text" name="author">
        <label for="quote">Quote</label>
        <input type="text" name="quote">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>


def delete_quote(request, review_id):
    quote = Quote.objects.get(id = quote_id)
    if quote.user.id == request.session['user_id']:
        quote.delete()
    else:
        messages.error(request, "This isn't yours to delete.")
    return redirect(f'/main')
```

Comment: what's going on with `delete_quote` taking in a `review_id` but then trying to use a (presumably undefined) `quote_id` to delete with?

Comment: Thats my mistake Im re using old code. I just changed it to quote_id but still its not appearing when I run the server

Answer (score 0):

First create a html page asking them really they want to delete or not

```html
{% extends 'main.html'%}

{% block content %}

<form method = "POST" action = "">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> Are you sure you want to delete "{{obj}}"?</p>
    <a href = "{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}" >Go Back</a>
    <input type = 'submit' value='Confirm'/>

</form>


{% endblock content %}
```

then create a delete view like this

```py
def deleteQuote(request,pk):
    quote = Quote.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.user != quote.user:
        return HttpResponse("You can't delete quote")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            quote.delete()
    return render(request,'pages/delete.html',{'obj':quote})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! That makes sense Ive done something similar in the past but how do I create a link in my main page that connects individual quotes so they redirect to the new HTML? Maybe I should have clarified but the code I used for deleting does not work! This code specifically idk why its not working                                                                                           {% if quote.user.id == request.session.user_id %}
        <a href='reviews/{{quote.id}}/delete'>Delete this quote</a>
        {% endif %}

Comment: Create an 'a' tag like this <a href = 'add the link of that html page'>Delete</a> , This creates a link to that new html page. when ever you click on delete it will redirect to that html page. add this 'a' tag inside for loop you created to display quotes. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) . see this link for refernce.